# implement circular queue with epoll wakeup for reading

Tags: c, linux, file, epoll

I have a thread using epoll.
I have multiple types of fd registered, including sockets and pipes. I'd like to add another type of fd 'queue read'.

I'm trying to implement a fixed-size circular queue in memory, so that a reader has an fd which can be registered with epoll.

A background thread will write to the queue and I'd like to block said thread if the queue is full.

Is there a simple way to create a fixed size file in memory?

Is it possible to implement the blocking write with a simple call to `write`?